# Create date column from 3 strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
(integer)    (integer)       (varchar(50))
  Month         Year            Color
    1           2019             Blue
    1           2019             Yellow
    1           2019             Red
    2           2019             Blue
    2           2019             White
```

My end goal is to be able to make a query like this:

```
Select Color from table where (cast(concat(Year,'/',Month,'/1') as date)>='01/Jan/2019' and cast(concat(Year,'/',Month,'/1') as date)<'1/Mar/2019')
```

What i want is to be able to create a date from the columns i have in order to do a query within a range of dates.

I tried making the date with this query but it gives me this error:

```
Select cast(concat(Year,'/',Month,'/1') as date) from table
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

**Solution:**

This is the final query that i used to get the dates in a Fiscal Year from Oct-2017 to Sep-2018.

```
select distinct(DATEFROMPARTS(y,m,1))
from table
where 
(DATEFROMPARTS(y, m, 1) >= cast('2017-10-01' as date)) and (DATEFROMPARTS(y, m, 1) < cast('2018-10-01' as date))
order by DATEFROMPARTS(y,m,1)
```

**Edit**

Edited to switch cast to datefromparts

```
select distinct(DATEFROMPARTS(y,m,1))
from table
where 
(DATEFROMPARTS(y, m, 1) >= DATEFROMPARTS(2017, 10, 1)) and (DATEFROMPARTS(y,m, 1) < DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 10, 1))
order by DATEFROMPARTS(y,m,1)
```

Comment: `cast('2017-10-01' as date` is just plain **outdated horror**. Never use this. Use `datefromparts(2017, 10, 1)`instead

Comment: Changed it Thanks

Comment: **Just great!**

Comment: @SQLPolice Please elaborate on "outdated horror"

Comment: @JohnCappelletti 1) The format "2017-01-01" cannot always be interpreted in localized versions. 2) Counter-Question: Why would you use a complicated cast when you can use datefromparts?

Comment: @SQLPolice OK, I get your context for non ANSI compliant.    Like I tell my kids, NEVER and ALWAYS are really big words.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I tell my kids: Talk with computers **as exact as possible**.

Comment: @SQLPolice Clearly you are more passionate about cast() and datefromparts() than I am.  They're just tools in my box.  Surely you've had to consume data where the dates where NOT in parts.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Surely I am living in Europe and in 30 years, I had unbelievingly many troubles with localized date and number formats. Especially months and days mixed up. Therefore, I avoid "casting" whereever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datefromparts()`:

```
select color 
from table 
where 
    datefromparts(year, month, 1) >= cast('20190101' as date)
    and datefromparts(year, month, 1) < cast('20190301' as date)
```

Or:

```
where 
    datefromparts(year, month, 1) >= datefromparts(2019, 1, 1)
    and datefromparts(year, month, 1) < datefromparts(2019, 3, 1)
```

Since you are forcing the date to the first date of the month, you could also use `between` like so:

```
select color 
from table 
where datefromparts(year, month, 1) 
    between cast('20190101' as date) and cast('20190201' as date)
```

Or:

```
where datefromparts(year, month, 1) 
    between datefromparts(2019, 1, 1) and datefromparts(2019, 2, 1)
```

Note that for this date range, you could as well do simple number comparison:

```
where year = 2019 and month in (1, 2)
```

However if your date range spans over multiple years, this will get tedious and require a more complex expression.

Comment: why the cast? how about `where datefromparts(year, month, 1) >= datefromparts(2019, 1, 1)` ? 
BTW, it's **datefromparts**. not datefrompart.

Comment: @SQLPolice: I fixed the typo on `datefromparts()`, thanks for this. I don't see anything wrong with using `cast` here (it just makes things explicit), although, of course, there are alternatives.

Comment: @SQLPolice if you use the ANSI compliant string format of YYYMMDD it will work regardless of localization. It is the only string literal format that is always interpreted the same in any situation. But I agree that datefromparts is almost always a better idea.

Comment: OK thanks to both of you for your comments: I updated the answer to use ISO formats and also mentionned the `datefromparts()` solution.